# Even though the try block can read the file, the method still returns null. How do I get it to return the expected string?

Tags: java, file-io, io, try-catch

So the test runs to see if the method can read the file and return its contents. I've tried different alterations and this is what I've come to so far. I was able to print out all the necessary contents in the while loop, but once outside that loop, fileContents returns "null".

```
public static String readTestResults(String fileName) {

        BufferedReader reader;
        String fileContents = " ";

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            fileContents = reader.readLine();

            while (fileContents != null) {
                System.out.println(fileContents);
                fileContents = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();
            System.out.println("test: " + fileContents);
            return fileContents;
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Print if code reaches here");
        return fileContents;
```

I've added multiple print statements to try and pinpoint where the code could be bugged. It never reaches to final one. So far my results are:

```
Alex,Smith,99,A
Jolene,Schmidt,100,A
Mackinzie,Jensen,86,B
test: null
```

I need it to return just that list of names but just returns null.

I believe it could be a format error of mine but as now I am stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for `BufferedReader#readline`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), it clearly states *"or null if the end of the stream has been reached without reading any characters"*. Then look at your loop exit condition, `while (fileContents != null) {`, this would mean that `fileContents` will be `null` after the loops exit, which is why when you do `return fileContents;` you're return `null`

Comment: The question is, do you want to return a `String` of ALL the contents or do you want to parse each line of the file and return a `List` of values instead

Comment: If you just want to read the contents of the file, you could use [`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) which will return a `List<String>`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I would like to return a String of all the contents.

Comment: @MadProgrammer ah I see. That while loop is there to read the next line in the file. I tried changing that parameter to reader.readLine() != null but then it only returns the second line from the file.

Comment: You've already read the first line, see my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by having a look at the [JavaDocs for BufferedReader#readline](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()), it clearly states *"or null if the end of the stream has been reached without reading any characters"*.

Then look at your loop exit condition, `while (fileContents != null) {`, this would mean that `fileContents` will be `null` after the loops exit, which is why when you do `return fileContents;` you're returning `null`

If you just want to return a single `String` representing the entire contents of the file, you could, instead, do something like...

```
public static String readTestResults(String fileName) {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            joiner.add(line);
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now, personally, I wouldn't consume the exception here, instead I'd throw it, for example...

```
public static String readTestResults(String fileName) throws IOException {
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(System.lineSeparator());
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            joiner.add(line);
        }
        return joiner.toString();
    }
}
```

It then becomes the responsibility of the caller to handle the error, which makes more sense then returning a `null` or empty `String`.

You may also find it easier use [`Files#readAllLines`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path)) which will return a `List<String>` - this will be easier to parser IMHO.

You'll also want to take a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to understand how that code is actually working and why you should be using it.

Comment: Looking at the your while conditional and having it return null at the end had me try something similar to my code and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: The "problem" is, `String` concatenation in Java is expensive, so in general, it's recommend to make use of things like `StringBuilder` and `StringJoiner`. The way I've set this up will you allow to make use of `Scanner#nextLine` to parse each line

Comment: Yes! I ended up having to use StringBuffer actually and that worked perfectly! Thank you again!